# To Perform customized Bivariate Analysis of all types(categorical VS Numerical, Numerical VS Numerical, Categorical VS Categorical)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization, data-analysis

I've to perform a customized bivariate analysis, where from a single function I can perform all types of bivariate analysis(categorical VS Numerical, Numerical VS Numerical, Categorical VS Categorical).

I've to perform this analysis in-depth and I've searched out a lot of sources but was unable to find the correct source to follow.

I'm trying to perform the analysis in as much depth as possible.

Any leads on this will be extremely helpful.

Comment: This is too general for stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic